# Apple Watch assumes incorrect birthday for its owner

Tags: apple-watch, time

This morning, December 25th, I noticed my Apple Watch wished me a Happy Birthday:

[image]

That is strange, since it's actually *tomorrow*, 26th, as indicated on my iPhone 11 (Settings app → Apple ID → Name, Phone Numbers, Email):

[image]

What's going on here? I can hardly imagine time zone issues (I'm at UTC+1). As far as I can remember, in the past years it had the day right, but I did buy a new Watch (Series 7 Nike) this year. If it matters, I have the latest OS versions installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your My Card in the Phone app, at the top of the Contacts tab or ask Siri "whose phone is this?" and tap the resulting card.

Make sure the Birthday field in the card is accurate and tap the "birthday" field title to choose the calendar to use.

[image]

Neither your Apple ID birthday nor Medical ID birthday are used for the Apple Watch birthday greeting, only your My Card in Contacts.